# ReactsTrap is not rendering my Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

- components: `Catalog`
- reactstrap version `#4.8.0`
- react version `#16.2.0`
- bootstrap version `#4.0.0`

**What is happening?**

Modal is not rendering in my HTML -> inspecting it shows nothing. creates error on toggling.

**What should be happening?**

Modal should be at least rendering in the DOM.

Error message in console
on toggling: TypeError: this._dialog is undefined

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ItemsTable from '../../modules/ItemsTable/ItemsTable';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

class Catalog extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    itemsData: [],
    modal : false
  };
  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}

toggle(){
  this.setState({modal : !this.state.modal});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={this.toggle}>Klik!</Button>
      <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={"modalThing"}>
      <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

}

export default Catalog

Comment: hi.. did you solved this..? please let me know how..

Comment: Hi, it was an issue regarding react and reactstrap versions not working together. Check out this link for more info and the solution. https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/908#issuecomment-381606160